# Can I hide my YouTube link in my Google+ profile and disassociate the two?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

Can I hide my YouTube link in my Google+ profile and disassociate the two?

Answer (score 4):

Google+ Help Official Answer

> The only information that is always public is your profile name, your
>   profile image and cover photo, and the link to the YouTube channel
>   connected to your Google+ profile or page.

Therefore hiding YouTube link from the Google+ Profile is not possible at the moment.

Source: https://plus.google.com/107150983484568200135/posts/ckCoUm2X3Sa

Comment: Please summarize what's at the link within the body of your answer, that way if the link goes stale, the information is still here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disconnect your YouTube channel from Google+.

- Go to YouTube Settings
- Click on "Disconnect channel from Google+" (next to your avatar)
- On the next page, tick "I understand that my channel will be renamed."
- Click "Rename Channel."

Source:  [Why can't I hide my youtube link on my Google+ profile?](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130409095232AAm6Vkk)

Answer (score 1):

- Go to https://myaccount.google.com/
- *Account Management* → *Remove YouTube Content* > *Hide my profile*
- Check five boxes

You're good to go!

Took me forever to find this and I can't figure out how to re-enable it just yet—that is, if you wanted to.